# LUA - Calling function from other module without exporting table

Tags: lua, prosody-im

I try to setup a special behavior with Jitsi, but have not that much LUA knowlege.

A Jitsi/Prosody module "mod_muc_lobby_rooms.lua" is implementing some function like  `handle_create_lobby(event);`. `handle_create_lobby` is calling other sub-function from inside.

https://github.com/jitsi/jitsi-meet/blob/master/resources/prosody-plugins/mod_muc_lobby_rooms.lua

But the module itself is not a library module, so no table is exported and another code can use "require". So my understanding from LUA yet.

For a own module, I just want use this functions from the other side, without reimplement or copy/paste it.

Is there any solution, how I can "source" the function into my module?

If possible, I want let "mod_muc_lobby_room.lua" unchanged, if some updates from Jitsi are coming.

Thanks in advance.

A lua beginner, Uwe

Comment: Function `handle_create_lobby` is a global function.  The module `mod_muc_lobby_room` saves this function to global variables, so after that the function is available to all your code.

Comment: @EgorSkriptunoff not sure about this `Attempt to read a non-existent global 'handle_create_lobby'`.

Comment: This means you have not loaded the library before trying to access the global variable.

Comment: Thanks for hints, but it was not working, because the modul "mod_muc_lobby_rooms" was loaded within another prosody phase (VirtualHost a vs. b). For me it looks like the modules do not see each other. But finally the answer from L3opold helped me alot. It works for me. So I can build my own module, using function from other module.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can fire an event because it [listen for it](https://github.com/jitsi/jitsi-meet/blob/stable/jitsi-meet_5390/resources/prosody-plugins/mod_muc_lobby_rooms.lua#L430).

```lua
prosody.events.fire_event("create-lobby-room", event)
```

Or you can use the module function like this:

```lua
local muc_lobby_rooms = module:depends("muc_lobby_rooms");
muc_lobby_rooms.handle_create_lobby(event);
```

Comment: Thanks L3opold. Works great. So I can build my own module and enable by default the lobby, when a room organisator is starting the room with a JWT.
You made my day :-)

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like that:

```
file=io.open("mod_muc_lobby_room.lua")
io.input(file)
load(io.read("*a"))()
io.close(file)
```

And the code located in mod_muc_lobby_room.lua will be executed.

Comment: If ```loadfile('mod_muc_lobby_room.lua')()``` or ```dofile('mod_muc_lobby_room.lua')``` not available/working?